# PUT / POST unknown length blob to Apache / PHP

Tags: php, apache, http, streaming

I know that http requires a Content-Length header for POST and PUT requests. Is there a way around this limitation without using websockets? Maybe using somehow chunked transfer encoding?

I mean, how would someone create a client application that streams from a client's webcam to a (Apache/PHP) server which would then save or broadcast the file in "real time"?

Actually I would use it for another use-case: zipping files and streaming the zip to the server at the same time, but the aforementioned use-case seems more *mainstream* (sorry for the pun).

I've tried the obvious: just doing it without a content-length, but the server just complains with a `Bad Content-Length!` error.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use chunked encoding.